# Chromecast MediaRoute icon disappears from Actionbar when loading video thumbail

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast, material-design, android-actionbaractivity

I have chromecast app which is working fine, but I have now implemented Material Design with Actionbar where I am showing Chromecast MediaRoute icon as action. The issue is I got video listview in the ActionBarActivity where I am showing list of videos along-with video thumbnail. When I try to load video thumbnails in the thread the Cast icon disappears.But when I don't use code which sets video thumbnail in a Thread, Cast button appears.

[image]

Code for Cast MediaRoute Icon as action on Action bar:

```
  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.cast_menu, menu);
        MenuItem media_route_menu_item = menu.findItem(R.id.media_route_menu_item);
        MediaRouteActionProvider provider = (MediaRouteActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(media_route_menu_item);
        provider.setRouteSelector(mediaRouteSelector);
        return true;
    }
```

Code for displaying thumbnail:

```
public void UpdateThumbnailImageForListItem()
{
    try {

        boolean started = false;

        MyViewItem myViewItem = (MyViewItem)myViewItemQueue.poll();

        if(myViewItem != null && myViewItem.getView() != null){
              ViewHolder holder;
              holder = (ViewHolder) myViewItem.getView().getTag(); //getViewHolderFromView(myViewItem.getView());

            Bitmap bmThumbnail,fixedSizeThumbnail;
            List<VideoListItem> items = MyCastSampleGlobals.getInstance().getVideoListItems();      
            if(items != null && holder != null)
            {
                //lets use title for now as key
                String viewTitle = getVideoTitle(holder);
                VideoListItem vItem = getVideoListItemForTitle(viewTitle);
                if(vItem != null)
                {
                    String path = vItem.getFilePath();
                    bmThumbnail = getVideoFrame(path);//ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path, Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
                    fixedSizeThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(bmThumbnail, 150, 100); 
                    holder.imageview.setImageBitmap(fixedSizeThumbnail);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Thread.sleep(2000);
        }

    //    RunOnUIThreadUpdateUIThumbnailView();

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

In OnCreate:

```
Thread myThread;
Runnable runnable = new StatusRunner();
myThread = new Thread(runnable);
logVIfEnabled(TAG, "Starting statusRunner thread");
myThread.start();
```

Code of Runnable:

```
 private class StatusRunner implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                try {
                    updateStatus();
                    updateProgressBar();

                    doThumbnailLoad();

                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Thread interrupted: " + e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

doThumbnailload function code:

```
  private void doThumbnailLoad()
    {
        if(castSampleNewAdapter != null)
        {

            castSampleNewAdapter.UpdateThumbnailImageForListItem();
        }
    }
```

Any help in solving this issue will be really great.

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/implementing-material-design-in-your.html  are you now using "toolbar" as recommended?

Answer (score 0):

see [setupactionbar](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android/blob/master/src/com/google/sample/cast/refplayer/VideoBrowserActivity.java) method in the sample app and finish MD migration by substituting "Toolbar" for the older actionbar and you should be good with the cast icon's appearance in the toolBar's view.